# Using AJAX Control Toolkits NumericUpDown Control with Comma as Decimal Separator

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, culture, decimal-point

We are trying to use the `NumericUpDown` Control from the AJAX Control Toolkit, but can find no way to make it use a comma as a decimal separator instead of a point. Other controls such as the `Calendar` will automatically use the Page Culture and adapt their content according to it. Do anyone know a way to change the Decimal Separator?